# Cannot use Angular 1 directive in Angular 2 app using upgradeNg1Component()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular

I am trying to make a hybrid angular app using Angular 1 & 2. I have a simple angular 1 directive:

```
var sample = angular.module('interestApp',[]);
sample.directive('myComp', function() {
  return {
    scope:{},
restrict: 'E',
template: '<div>My name is </div>'
}
});
```

I want to use this directive  in my angular 2 app. So I convert it using upgradeNg1Component() like this:

```
const upgradeAdapter: UpgradeAdapter = new UpgradeAdapter();
upgradeAdapter.bootstrap(document.body, ['interestApp']);
@Component({
    selector: 'angular2',
    template: '<myComp></myComp>',
    directives: [upgradeAdapter.upgradeNg1Component('myComp')]
})
```

I am getting this error when I run it though:

```
EXCEPTION: No provider for $scope! (function (scope, elementRef)
```

Can anyone help with this? Or if anyone knows any other way of using angular 1 directive in angular 2 application that would be really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You code looks good so far, but it seems like there's one part missing. While you upgrade your ng1 component to use it in your Angular 2 component with the selector `angular2` (which I would suggest to change), you don't downgrade that Angular 2 component again to actually use it in your bootstrapped Angular 1 application.

That's something you always have to do as long as you're in the process of upgrading your app. In order to get your Angular 2 component instantiated, you need to use it in your A1 as a directive and therefore it needs to be downgraded. So you'd need to do sth. like:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-ng2-component',
    template: '<myComp></myComp>',
    directives: [upgradeAdapter.upgradeNg1Component('myComp')]
})
class MyNg2Component {

}

angular.module('interestApp', [])
    .directive('myComponent', {...})
    .directive('myNg2Component', upgradeAdapter.downgradeNg2Component(MyNg2Component);

upgradeAdapter.bootstrap(document.body, ['interestApp']);
```

As soon as you're done with upgrading you can remove all the Angular 1 specifc parts and the downgrading mechanisms.

Comment: Thanks, the directive now shows up when I downgrade the ng2 component. But I am still getting the 'No provider for $scope' error.

Comment: @swapp1990 Did you ever find a solution to the $scope injection error?  I'm running into this  as well.

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML, are you referencing both versions of the component/directive?

For me, this would occur any time that I referenced the Angular2 version of a component that was both:

1. downgraded to AngularJS
2. referenced an upgraded AngularJS directive in its template.

In my case, I defined `<ng2-component>` for NG2 and `<downgraded-ng2-component>` for NG1 and was referencing them both in my HTML.  This resulted in the error.

I found that in my use of Angular 2.0.0-beta.0 that I have to avoid using the original Angular2 component when it met both cases (1) and (2) from above.

Comment: No, I never reference the '<downgraded-ng2-component>' in my html, just the original Angular2 component. Are you saying I have to avoid using the original component? Because I want the Angular 1 directive '<my-comp>' to be a part of template inside the original component, I cannot avoid it.

Comment: That was my experience (don't know if it is a problem with my code or the beta status of Angular), but I cannot successfully use an Angular2 component with a template that employs an upgraded Angular1 directive.  However, if I downgraded that same Angular2 component I could successfully use its Angular1 incarnation.

Ultimately, I don't find this to be acceptable behavior and still believe a true solution is in order.  The "answer" I submitted is more of a "workaround".